# How to infor log every function in Controller Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, logging

During development I need to log everything in every function
Like as

```
class ExampleController extends Controller
{
      function myFunction($param1, $param2){
          Log::info("Start ExampleController@myFunction",[
              'param1' => $param1,
              'param2' => $param2,
          ]);
          
          // Code process at here

         Log::info("End ExampleController@myFunction",[
              'result' => $result
          ]);
      }
}
```

How to automatically execute without rewriting multiple lines of code in each function?
Automatically write log with class and function runned?

Comment: Create middleware and add log code on that!

Comment: Did you tried it? Please mark as complete if is relevant!

Comment: You probably want to debug, troubleshoot, but never to log ALL the functions.

Answer (score 0):

Will give you one example that might work for you.

```
php artisan make:middleware CustomLog
```

Open that file and add code like below

```
<?PHP

namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class CustomLog
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
       $response = $next($request);
       if (app()->environment('local')) {
       // Do you required changes is this array
       $log = [
            'URI' => $request->getUri(),
            'METHOD' => $request->getMethod(),
            'REQUEST_BODY' => $request->all(),
            'RESPONSE' => $response->getContent()
        ];
        Log::info(json_encode($log));
     }
     return $response;
    }
 }
```

New step is Open Kernel file. Assign a key custom.log to your middleware.

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'custom.log' => CustomLog::class
];
```

And the final step is

```
Route::get('function', 'AuthController@function')->middleware('custom.log');
```

Comment: Thank for answer, but it no match with my issue.  I need log all function in Controller my write. Information log consists of  "Start <ClassName>@<FunctionName> and parameters input" and "End <ClassName>@<FunctionName  and parameters output". It no need response is HTML, just need only data native